# Examples of great tag wikis

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, faq-proposed

I feel very comfortable editing questions and answers to improve their content. I've been doing that for a while and after asking questions on Meta Stack Overflow and reviewing others' edits, I feel I understand what makes a good question/answer edit and what does not. I am less comfortable in creating and editing [tag wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/tag-wiki/info). On one Area 51 site beta I am participating in, there are hardly any tag wikis, and when I tried to create one, I did a very poor job and my edit was (rightfully so) rejected.

I think seeing some examples of *great* tag wikis would really help me. What are some examples of really well done tag wikis, *across the entire network*? I'd really like to see them for a variety of topics, not *just* Stack Overflow.

Comment: To clarify are you asking about great examples of full tag wikis or excepts?

Comment: @BenBrocka Asking for examples of full, complete tag wikis, since CogSci has none.

Comment: +1, and this would be good to include in the [meta-tag:faq].

Answer (score 17):

> What are some examples of really well done tag Wikis?

The [Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info) one. My goodness. If every wiki looked like that....

Comment: "viewed 323 times". I'm not even sure what the point is

Comment: @Michael true, but who cares? It's a great tag wiki nevertheless... IIRC though, it wasn't written specially for the tag wiki, it's an excerpt from some other Scala resource.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek We've only been recording views on tag wikis for ~1.5 weeks.

Comment: **Thank you Pekka!** This is a great example, and shows me a lot about what should be done. I love how they list frequently asked questions. I really should be paying more attention to tag wikis!

Answer (score 5):

I think it's important that a tag wiki not only covers:

- What the tag is about
- What the tag is *not* about

But also:

- How to use the tag appropriately (e.g. more specific tags if needed)
- What similar tags or alternative exist on the site

---

Here's a list of some that I think are good representation of the above. Although I wouldn't mind others improving on what we already have.

#### Super User:

- [Microsoft Office](https://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-office/info)
- [Windows](https://superuser.com/tags/windows/info)
- [Mac](https://superuser.com/tags/mac/info)
- [Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/tags/osx/info)

Comment: As always, it'd be nice for others to edit in their favorites.

Comment: Mmmm, those Super User tag Wikis are great in their own right, but I think there can be more to a tag wiki than that: Frequently asked questions in that tag; where to learn basics; frequently occurring problems; etc. I saw a really great one (IMO) a few days back, I'll try to find it again

Comment: @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm You're right. Although – relatively speaking – I haven't really seen this done often, at least on SU. The good old problem with empty tag wikis.

Comment: @Pekka, slhck: What do you think of [ssh](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/ssh/info), [debian](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/debian/info), [shell](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/shell/info)?

Comment: @Gilles Excellent, I guess we have to learn a bit on SU.