# What is the optimal length of a tag excerpt?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki-excerpt

What is the optimal length of a tag excerpt?

The guidelines are pretty unclear: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/

And a sample of a quite long excerpt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript

It looks bad IMO when adding javascript tag to a question - if this was something less known than javascript, I think it would not be read. Moreover, this excerpt has still 170+ characters left! Imagine how it would look if it was completely filled.
[image: adding javascript tag]

For me, the descriptions we see above for [performance](/questions/tagged/performance) and [javascript-events](/questions/tagged/javascript-events) are much better: short, clear, quick to read.

What do you think? What is the official standpoint?

Comment: Not directly related but this would be a helpful read: [Examples of great tag wikis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120586/examples-of-great-tag-wikis)

Comment: A suggestion: Don't focus on length, focus on content

Answer (score 4):

> What is the optimal length of a tag excerpt?

As short as possible, as long as necessary.

I agree the JS tag wiki description is difficult to read, but the stuff in there has amassed over time and is there for good reason: it addresses issues that frequently come up in questions in that tag.

Trying to enforce an uniform length will hardly be successful, nor will it make a lot of sense. Tags will always have differing needs here.

Comment: As short as possible, as long as necessary. Great sentence.. could apply to all things in life - can I steal it

Comment: Sure - I'm sure I've stolen it from somewhere, too