# What menial tasks can I do to help communities on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion

I am sometimes bored (or procrastinating) and surf around various Stack Exchange communities. There are times when I am too tired to read complex questions and answers and am looking for short tasks that do not require a high cognitive load.

So far I have been:

- checking new questions for being "too broad", "not a question", etc. and flagging them
- checking the review queue in the only community I have over 2000 reputation

This only keeps me busy for a few minutes.

Are there some other menial activities I can do without being a moderator  (except doing actual work :)) that would actually have a positive effect on Stack Exchange?

Comment: You have access to review queues at 500. You have two sites where you can review and almost there at a third one.

Comment: @Oded: OK, was not aware of this. Although with 500 my selection is rather limited.

Comment: One thing I like to do is to use the SEDE to search for highly-viewed or highly-voted posts and correct typos or grammatical errors in order to present a better "face" for the site. With low rep, you'd need substantial a edit and review approval. The [toolkit](https://github.com/AstroCB/Stack-Exchange-Editor-Toolkit) helps with that.

Comment: Also you can [Edit Questions and Answers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: @JeffSchaller: What is SEDE?

Comment: Sorry; Stack Exchange Data Explorer: http://data.stackexchange.com/ ; also the [tag:data-explorer] tag here.

Comment: @JeffSchaller that is an answer!

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of enabling your procrastination, but in the hopes of reducing your boredom and improving Stack Exchange, here are some ideas:

- vote up Questions -- help your site differentiate questions that are useful, appropriate, clear, and/or well-researched from ... the rest of the questions.
- add bounties to Questions that you feel could use more attention (appearing on the "featured" questions page).
- vote up Answers -- reward answers that you deem useful to their Question.
- vote down Questions -- for those that do *not* show signs of being useful, appropriate, clear, or well-researched.
- vote down Answers -- for those that do *not* address the Question, or are not useful or clear; or are dangerous, etc.
- submit new (or update existing) tag excerpts and wikis -- if you click on the "/tags" link for the site, do all of the most popular tags on the first page have good excerpts and wikis? Are there new tags that appear useful but do not have good excerpts or wikis?

  - Reference: [Redesigned Tags Page](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/)
  - [Examples of great tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120586/examples-of-great-tag-wikis)
- participate in the Meta site(s) -- vote on questions and answers there; ask if there are particular cleanup tasks that are underway that could use your help; add your input to existing questions, or ask new ones.
- participate in the site's chat room -- see if there are discussions going on that you can join, or start a new one!

Beyond that, you can also submit Edits for Questions and Answers:

- correct grammar mistakes and/or typos
- improve titles to better reflect the question
- add or remove tags to questions

I often use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) to create queries to support various efforts; some examples that I've created for myself are:

- finding questions that have used a tag that the site deemed should be retired or consolidated into a different tag
- finding questions that have used a combination of tags that the site disagrees with
- finding questions that have not accepted an answer; is there a reasonable answer there? Is the asker new and didn't realize they should accept one? Is there not yet an acceptable answer?
- search for posts with grammatical errors that you can fix; I further enhance this search by requiring the score to be above zero and that the post is not "closed" (to avoid spending time on questions or answers that have already been deemed less worthy).

Comment: Not all these tasks are no-brainers/menial.